# How to proxy a HTTP request completely by PHP?

Tags: php, proxy, header, httprequest, transfer

In some PHP projects, I need to use PHP as a proxy. Below, there are examples of what I mean:

Non-Proxied requests: Website A sends data to website B and B returns responses to A.
Proxied requests: Website A sends data to website C, website C sends data to website B, Website B sends response to B, and B returns the same data to A.

May you help me how can I send the whole of retrieve HTTP request (Data, headers, etc.) to a new domain without missing anything, and return the response to another domain?

Comment: C can use `curl` to send the request to B. Use the curl option to return the headers. Then for each of the headers that curl returns, call the PHP `header()` function to return them to the client.

Comment: Why do you need to do this with PHP? Why not use a real proxy server?

Comment: Please share more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem or any more specific question about this

Comment: @Barmar, each project might require some special changes on its behavior before forwarding to another server. This is why I need to have control on operations by a programming language.

Comment: @NicoHaase, I have tried https://github.com/jenssegers/php-proxy, but it returns multiple errors and seems it does not work correctly. As the errors depend on many libraries, it is time consuming to solve them one by one. I am seeking a short and simple solution if it is available.